# How are linux buffers implemented?

Tags: buffer

I am a new to linux kernel internals. I am trying to understand linux buffer management. I am looking at buffer_head.h and blkdev.h. I am finding it quite complicated how linux manages buffers. Are these the correct source files? What does "struct buffer_head" do?

Also, are blocks similar to buffers?

Can you give me a rough idea of buffer_head.h and blkdev.h do?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Book Understanding.the.Linux.Kernel.3rd.Edition, Chapter 15 the page cache, to get some overview of the buffer management.